# Why doesn't the grand total in this power pivot table sum all columns correctly?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerbi, powerpivot

For some reason, the grand total here does not sum both columns. Any idea what could be the problem here?

[image]

[image]

This was created via a tabular project / model in Visual Studio.

I have no idea how to tackle this problem (our guy who did BI left the company and now I have to pick up the tab and I'm new to this world).

I don't know if it's a model problem or if there is some configuration I need to change for the pivot table so that it sums things properly. Anyone have any idea? Thanks.

Here's the related measures:

```
Combined Sum Amount QTD:=[Rev Exp Sum Amount QTD] + [HV Sum Amount QTD]

Rev Exp Sum Amount QTD:=IF(HASONEVALUE(Calendar[Period Ending]),
CALCULATE([Rev Exp Sum Amount ITD], LASTDATE(Calendar[Date]))-OPENINGBALANCEQUARTER([Rev Exp Sum Amount ITD],Calendar[Date]),BLANK())

HV Sum Amount QTD:=IF(HASONEVALUE(Calendar[Period Ending]),
CALCULATE([HV Sum Amount ITD], LASTDATE(Calendar[Date]))-OPENINGBALANCEQUARTER([HV Sum Amount ITD],Calendar[Date]),BLANK())
```

Comment: There is not enough information to help you. The issue is most likely somewere in the DAX formula, and/or data model (both can be found in Tabular). Pivot table options are not relevant here. Word of warning: Tabular has a pretty steep learning curve (contrary to the first impressions), and if you are new to it, I highly recommend to read at least one good book first - there are just too many new concepts behind the platform.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the DAX code for the `Combined Sum Amount QTD` measure

Comment: I will add it in a second.

Comment: @Olly, I added the measures.